# Executing a switch statement?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std ;
 int main() {
//Variables
char country;
int taxed ;
float pay ;
char uk_tax = 'a'; //40%
char us_tax ='b';//mulitple by number devide answer by 100

//Inputs
cout << "Enter your total earnings: ";
cin  >> pay ;
cout << "Are you within the UK or USA?\n ";
cout << "a) For Uk b) For USA \n  ";
cin >> country ;


switch(country)
{
case 1:
        //chosen if input is a
        if (country == uk_tax )
        taxed = 40 * pay / 100;
        cout<< "Here are your earnings after Tax £" << taxed  ;
        break;

    case 2:
        //chosen if input is b
        if (country == us_tax)
         taxed = 28 * pay / 100 ;
        cout << "Here are your earning after Tax £" << taxed ;
        break;
          } return 0 }
```

hello i was just wondering if anyone could help see the problem i'm having with this code. The code does not execute  the switch statements.The code its self it just a tax calculator for two country (usa,uk) the user picks the country by entering 'a' or 'b' but i can't seem to get it to execute the switch statements after

Comment: Maybe because `country` isn't 1 or 2?

Comment: the cases are `'a'` and `'b'` not `1` and `2`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: `'a'` and `'b'`, actually.

Comment: You are also using redundant `if` cases within the `switch` itself.

Comment: Why do you think case 1 is chosen if the input is 'a'?

Comment: Apparently _you_ think that input `'a'` is `case 1`, but how on Earth is the compiler supposed to know that? It's not allowed to read the comments, even if it knew English (which it does not).

Comment: Since the value of `country` isn't `1` or `2` (the two cases you have), and there is no `default` switch case, then the switch does nothing (it "falls through" to the next statement).  That's how a switch statement works. You might want to review `switch` statement syntax in C.

Comment: In addition to the other problems, it looks like you're confusing the amount of tax with the amount remaining after tax.

Answer (score 3):

If your variable `country` is not 1 or 2 then the `switch` won't do anything.
Also your cases would probably be better if they were:

`case 'a':`

```
case 'b':
```

Answer (score 1):

Your comments indicate you want to switch on inputs `'a'` and `'b'`, yet you did not write any code to do that. Your code switches on inputs for which `country` is the ASCII code `1` or `2`, which you are going to struggle to type on your keyboard.

Write this:

```
case 'a':
```

and this:

```
case 'b':
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

`country` is a `char`. You probably want to switch over `'1'` and `'2'` or `'a'` and `'b'`.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking the user to enter `a` or `b` for the countries, your switch cases should be `case 'a':` and `case 'b':` to match.

Answer (score 0):

Since `country` is of type `char`, the switch will look try to match each case. In this instance, you want to use `case 'a'` and `case 'b'`, not `case 1` and `case 2`